# search engine with Tf-Idf in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

here is my code

```
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
 corpus = [
     "this is first document ","this is second document","this is third","which document is first", ]

 vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

X.toarray()
```

now 
this is what i want to do?

when i search `document` it should give me [ 1,2,4]documents(sentence)

when i search `first document` it should give me [1]documents(sentence)

when i search `second` it should give me [2]documents(sentence)

i want to do this with TfIdf (i can't do normal searching )

how can i do that?

Comment: do the `n-gram` , store 1-gram, 2-gram, 3-gram and then run the normal search. Or use embeddings and find cosine similarity or maybe create a 2 headed neural network for finding the similarity.

If you can do the task easily by linear search then why go for complex solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to ask yourself the question: what does the TfidfVectorizer do? The answer is: it transforms your documents into vectors. How can you proceed further? One solution is to transform your query also into a vector by using the vectorizer. Then, you can compare the cosine similarity between the transformed query vector and each of the vectors of the documents in your database. The document with the highest cosine similarity to your query vector is the most relevant one (at least according to the Vector space model).
Here https://towardsdatascience.com/tf-idf-for-document-ranking-from-scratch-in-python-on-real-world-dataset-796d339a4089 is an example implementation.